# Export Data of content page in pdf file

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin.forms, mobile, export

i' m working in xamarin forms mobile application ,i would like to export data from content page to pdf file in my smartphone Android,i use this code :

```
private void PDFExport_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridPdfExportingController pdfExport = new DataGridPdfExportingController();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    var exportToPdf = pdfExport.ExportToPdf(this.dataGrid, new DataGridPdfExportOption()
    {
        FitAllColumnsInOnePage = true,
    });
    exportToPdf.Save(stream);
    exportToPdf.Close(true);

        Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ISave>().Save("DataGrid.pdf", "application/pdf", stream);
}
```

and this is the code of interface ISave:

```
string Save(string ch,string s,MemoryStream fileStream);
```

an error appears when i test the code :
nullRéferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
this error appears in this line of code:

```
   DependencyService.Get<ISave>().Save("DataGrid.pdf","application/pdf", stream.ToArray());
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.

Comment: if you are getting a NullRef exception, you need to start by figuring out which object is null.  Most likely your dependency service is not registered correctly and the `Get<ISave>()` is returning null.  So you can either fix that, OR you can just use normal file I/O methods to save it.  Using `DependencyService` to save files is typically not necessary with the last several versions of XF.